# Bangkok Ayuttahaya by boat?

Tags: thailand, bangkok, riverboats

What are the most interesting options to take a boat trip from Bangkok to Ayuttahaya? What should I check / worry about?

[Edit]
I like to be slightly comfortable, not too posh, it is for my family (with 2 kids). I figure the 'average' will do. Can you recommend any companies?

Comment: What do you mean by "interesting"?  AFAIK, all boats on this route are cruises for tourists, and what you pay directly correlates with what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this itinerary does not exist anymore. There is only Bangkok to Nonthaburi.

Comment: The public ferries on the Chao Phraya indeed only run to Nonthaburi, but there are plenty of tourist cruises going up to Ayutthaya and back.

Answer (score 0):

This tour seems quite popular: https://www.viator.com/tours/Bangkok/Thailands-Ayutthaya-Temples-and-River-Cruise-from-Bangkok/d343-3685BKK26C

> - Day trip from Bangkok to Ayutthaya, former capital of Siam
> - Riverboat cruise along the Chao Phraya River from Ayutthaya
> - See Wat Mahathat and Buddha's head entwined in tree roots
> - English-speaking licensed guide
> - Pickup and drop-off from central Bangkok hotels